# python request (the Accept header should send a media type of application/json)

Tags: python

I am trying to get an API query into python. The command line

`-H 'Authorization:Bearer <access_token>' \`

`-H 'Accept:application/json'`

My code:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.website.com/', headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer <my_access_token>'})
```

returns that

```
{'errors': [{'code': 'media_type_not_acceptable',
   'message': 'The Accept header should send a media type of application/json'}],
 'type': 'error.list'}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried to set header to {'Authorization': 'Bearer <my_access_token>', 'Accept': 'application/json'} ?

Comment: Why didn't you set the `Accept` header?